# Reasons not to use custom actions in Visual Studio Setup project

Tags: visual-studio, wix, setup-project, custom-action

Earlier today I was discussing with someone that I found out you can use a custom action in Visual Studio Setup projects to execute your own Installer classes that you would normally run using InstallUtil (which works great for a new project I am working on).

Said person suggested that I avoid custom actions at all costs though, stating that the moment you need to use custom actions you need to come up with your own solution and said that this is something that is recognised by many people and has been for a long time.

I have had a search around and can't find a single forum in which anyone has expressed concerns about this, and I just want to know if anyone knows of any reason why custom actions should not be used?

I want to ensure I'm using the most reliable solution possible in my new project, and this has given me some concerns about my current approach, however the person I was discussing it with couldn't give me an example of why it's a bad idea, so I just want confirmation as to whether what they said holds water or not.

Comment: Look me up on skype if you ever want a complete understanding of the history and best practices here.

Comment: BTW, it's a whole nother convesation as why not to use Visual Studio Setup Projects at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a lot of reasons but it's a long and subjective conversation.  Here are a couple links to get you started.  In summary the thing to keep in mind is to maintain the declarative native of MSI ( author table data driven, transactional custom actions ) and work really, really hard to not introduce fragiltiy to your installer.    Because of the design of InstallUtil / Installer class custom actions, they are simply a non-starter.  Use WiX's DTF ( Deployment Tools Foundation ) managed custom action project types ( C# / VB.NET ) instead.

[Managed Code CustomActions, no support on the way and here's why](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/19/Managed-Code-CustomActions-no-support-on-the-way-and-heres)

[Custom actions are (generally) an admission of failure](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/Zataoca-Custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure)

Note, for the first link, the "technical" portion is OBE due to the release of DTF.  The strategic portion is somewhat optimistic IMO and discussed more in the second link.   Here's also some background from my own blog:

[MSI vs .NET](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2006/07/msi-vs-net.html)

[The Price of Ideology and a Great New Hope](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/05/price-of-ideology-and-great-new-hope.html)

[Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) Managed Custom Actions](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-custom.html)

Comment: thanks very much for the reading material! Just had a look through it all but I am now feeling slightly overwhelmed / confused about where to go now.

The reason I was using a custom action originally was actually something I could do purely in the setup project it turns out - that being adding a few registry entries.

I saw in your other comment you suggested setup projects may be worth avoiding so I'm feeling a bit sceptical now about going ahead with my current solution.

Do you happen to have any reading material that would be good for a noobie to WiX / DTF?

Comment: I should also add - I am very new to deployment development, all of my development in the past has been stuff that requires no setup. The goal for this installer is to register a single DLL and add some registry entries prior to the user starting the application.

Comment: I commend you for realizing very early in the process that MSI is a totally different beast.  There are some wix tutorial web sites out there, a book published packetpub and of course the wix users mailing list.   If the install is really as simple as you say, I could write it for you in about 15 minutes due to my experience level.

Comment: If you are able to write an install that does exactly what you need, it never trips a repair, you don't have any CA's and you don't expect your install to get more complicated, then go ahead and stay with it. Realize that Setup Projects are gone in VS11 as MSFT killed it finally. Otherwise I suggest switching to WiX and/or InstallShield Limited Edition. (free for VS customers)  There's also another approach: http://blog.iswix.com/2011/03/redemption-of-visual-studio-deployment.html

Comment: I did happen to come across that last night while having a read around (that Setup projects are no longer being deployed with VS), I think that's probably a good a sign as any to have a few weeks of learning WiX! Many thanks for the offer to write it too, but I'll stick it out as it should be a good learning experience (a good one, or a hair tearing one!)